# When I add new testers to TestFlight do I have to put out a new build for them to be "notified"?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight, beta

I added around 50 new testers to my external testing via TestFlight in iTunes Connect tonight, but a few hours later none of them have received an email, and the "status"/iOS column in the users list has nothing in it, while some users in previous additions have "Notified" or "Installed".

Do I have to push out a new build or something? Or is it just a matter of time until they get an email and change status to "Notified"?

Comment: What does the status column say in Build details and Activity->Testers tab for the indicated version?  Normally when an new version is uploaded the testers on that list get a notification

Answer (score 3):

in my usage, i add new external users to testflight, then click 'save' and within minutes the new external testers receive email from apple.  first time i did this it did not work because i added new users, but did not click 'save' button in upper right.  see screenshot, need to do both '1' and '2'.  my issue is some folks get notified and others do not, and i am going to post this question to stackoverflow.
[itunes connect screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egI4D.png)

Answer (score 0):

No you don't.
If you have a Testflight active and add some tester, iTunes Connect will ask for confirmation and the added users will be notified.

Nicolas